# Is there any recent problem with Chrome Metamask?

Tags: metamask

I was using MetaMask for google chrome. recently I realised when I send a transaction to a blockchain (e.g. private/local) all the transactions are pending. But if I do the same with Firefox metamask, it works fine.

Can anybody explain to me if I'm missing something or there's some problem.
I tested on MAC and linux, both have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is isn’t widespread. You can get some personal debugging at support.metamask.io

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So you can successfully deploy your contracts to a local chain via remix + Metamask ?

Comment: Yeah, metamask and remix is usually a great combination!